# El Capitan Server using SSL on Apache - AH01276: Cannot serve directory

Tags: macos, server.app, apache

El Capitan 10.11.4 **Server**

I've been accessing a php site I'm developing at http://localhost/myproject/web/
But after I turn on SSL for that route I get a 403

> You don't have permission to access /crm_tollring/web/ on this server.

In the Apache log is :

> AH01276: Cannot serve directory /Users/george/Sites/myproject/web/: No matching DirectoryIndex (index.html,index.php,/xcode/,/wiki/,default.html) found, and server-generated directory index forbidden by Options directive

So, I figure I have to remove the `Options -Indexes' directive from the apache conf for SSL... somewhere?

It seems like the configuration files for running the Apache instance is:
`/Library/Server/Migrated/private/etc/apache2/`

(even though configs also exist at `/private/etc/apache2/`)

I checked httpd-ssl.conf, but can't find it there.

Can someone can help me pinpoint the configuration for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is best done not by hand editing the *.conf files, but via the Server app, under `Server > Websites > Server Websites (SSL) > Edit > Edit Advanced Settings > Allow Folder Listing`

Answer (score 1):

You're right that in most cases, other than for very well-experienced Unix users, or those completely familiar with the older versions of OSX Server, it is best to configure things when possible with the **Server.app** GUI.  Making custom firewall tweaks, is the only thing that comes to mind immediately that I've done more than once or twice recently outside of the GUI.

You can configure the settings you need, for your */Users/george/Sites/myproject/web/* on the SSL sites entry, under **"Websites"** in **OSX Server**. See the image below:

[image: osx server - websites tab gui]

After clicking the appropriate website, click the pencil icon, to change the settings, and under **"Edit advanced settings"**, you can add the option "allow folder listings" in this window, as well as other options like using a custom error page (see the second image, below):

[image: osx server - websites - edit advanced options]

Comment: just what I said in my answer posted 4 days ago...

Comment: @Francis yup - pictures work well so this should have probably been an edit to your post. Either way - +1 to you both for the answers.

Comment: @Francis haha yeah, I had your original post back from when it had a bounty on it (disappeared now?) in my que of webpages I wanted to look at, and didn't realize you'd self answered.  Copy & paste if you think something is useful, np.

Comment: I think also that first bit I emphasized is really key too, because on Stack forums, loads of users are really, nicely experienced with old versions of OSX and BSDs and don't realize (and frustratingly so, sometimes) that Apple has moved so heavily into using Server.app now.